# Study extremes of convergence ratio of a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Study the extremes of the radio convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac n{2^n(2n-1)}{(x-1)}^n}\,.$$

---

I know that, by the radio test, the convergence of this series is for $x\in(-1,3)$. So let's study when:

- $\boxed{x=-1}:\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac n{2^n(2n-1)}{(-1-1)}^n}
  =\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac n{2^n(2n-1)}{(-1)}^n2^n}
  =\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{{(-1)}^n\underbrace{\frac{n}{2n-1}}_{a_n}}\,,
  $

so now I will apply Leibniz Rule for $a_n$:

I) $a_n\geq0$?: Yes;

II) $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=0$? NO, because $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n}{2n-1}}=\frac 12\neq 0,$$ therefore $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{{(-1)}^n\frac{n}{2n-1}}\qquad\text{diverges}.$$

Similarly, when

- $\boxed{x=3}:\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac n{2^n(2n-1)}{(3-1)}^n}
  =\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac n{2^n(2n-1)}2^n}
  =\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{n}{2n-1}}\qquad\text{diverges},
  $

therefore $$\boxed{\text{the series absolutely converges when}\qquad x\in(-1,3)}\quad\text{not }x\in[-1,3].$$

Is that ok?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course it’s the right result but more simply in both case it suffices to note that we have $$a_n \not \to 0$$ which is a necessary condition for convergence (we don’t need to refer to Leibniz).

Comment: Thank you! So that way is more simple, btw I liked knowing if my way was correct too. Hey... are you a moderator here? If not, [can I nominate you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28686/525384)?

Comment: @manooooh Yes the result is correct but you shouldn’t use Leibniz in the first since it is a test for convergence, what are you using is the basic fact that $a_n \not \to 0$. I think in an exam it could be penalized.

Comment: Oh `:(`. So we would say that $a_n\not\to0$ because $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n}{2n-1}}\neq0\;\text ?$$

Comment: @manooooh Thanks for your kind proposal but I am relatively new here and I don’t think to be ready to be a good moderator here. Maybe next time! Bye

Comment: @manooooh yes of course that’s always the first check to do, if $a_n\to 0$ the series could converge (and we need to consider some test to show whether it converges or diverges) otherwise we can conclude suddenly that the series diverges.

Comment: @manooooh Anyway I will support Aloizio Macedo election.

Comment: Good! I don't know his answers. Write something in his nomination `:)`. Btw I thought I can nominate you... you are precise in your answers and kind in answering the doubts in the comments!

Comment: @manooooh thanks I’ll continue so even if I’m not a moderator, moreover I think that a moderator needs to have other kind of attitudes, Aloizio for example is a good one, like many other users here